# Fragment Lifecycle functions usage in implementing an App

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Where can I find a full example of how these functions are used? I have read the Android Developers relevant articles but I would like to see something more complete to understand what piece of code I should write in each of these, like:

In `onCreateView()` function you have to declare your views (findViewById.. etc)

In `onAttach()` function you should do something else.. and so on.

For example I use Picasso library to display an image in a Fragment. I do this in `onCreateView()`, but sometimes `getActivity()` returns `null`, so the app crashes. In which lifecycle method should this code be in?

Thank you

Comment: Lifecyle of fragments can be studied here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I noticed that `getActivity` can return `null` when user enter a view (ie. a fragments is loaded) but quickly clicks back, and where back is another activity. The fragment is still loading up but it's activity is gone.